# Problema con la instalacion de tailwindcss

Tags: nodejs, express, tailwind

se me hace imposible compilar tailwind con "ES Modules" en mi proyecto no se si tenga que ver con que esto usando express y  pug  me genera error de compilation , me marca el siguiente error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1175:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:165:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:192:25)
```

Eso cuando utilizo Export default .

y cuando utilizo modules.imports :  el mismo error

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.